# javascript enemy move in direction

Tags: javascript, move, direction, trigonometry

you can test it here: http://xanderh.djoamersfoort.nl/informatica/spel3.php
(the police comes when you walk in a lazer)
I want that the police walks towards you (x,y) but this code doens't work:

```
function police_move_loop(){
var police_x = parseInt(document.getElementById("police1").style.left);
var police_y = parseInt(document.getElementById("police1").style.top);
var delta_x = x - police_x;
var delta_y = y - police_y;
var politie_dir = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x) * 180 / Math.PI;
politie_dir+=270;
document.getElementById("police").style.transform = "rotate("+politie_dir+"deg)";
var police_vec_x = Math.cos(police_dir * Math.PI / 180);
var police_vec_y = Math.sin(police_dir * Math.PI / 180);
document.getElementById("police1").style.left = police_x+police_vec_x+"px";
document.getElementById("police1").style.top  = police_y+police_vec_y+"px";
setTimeout("police_move_loop()",10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has to do with

```
document.getElementById("police1").style.top  = police_y+police_vec_y+"px";
```

Even after the police intersects with the player, the y coordinates drastically continue to change and still continues to call

```
setTimeout("police_move_loop()",10);
```

You probably want to add an if statement that checks when the center of the police matches the center of the player. Once the police and player collide like that, then the police_move_loop() should stop being called.